# Preview Meshes?

Tags: rendering, workflow

I often see animators or other artists on Youtube in behind the scenes and they often just work with a simple, low-poly model. They animate low-poly characters  and place trees and props around like nothing. And when they render it, by magic the software only takes the high-poly fully-modeled version to render.

How do I achieve this in Blender?

**EDIT**

Let's say I have a tree model. That tree has about 2.000.000 vertices. I now want to create a little forest with hand-placed trees. To be able to have about 10 trees at once in the viewport (20 mio verts), the viewport should show a low poly version of that tree I created (let's say 100 vertices). How do I link the high-poly and the low-poly tree so that I see one in the viewport, the other one in the rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of three methods...

[image]
One would be to use a subdivision or multiresolution modifier set to preview at low numbers.

[image]
Two would be to assign custom shapes to the bones of the character's armature,
 the shapes would be made to look like low poly versions of the parts of the mesh assigned to the bone.
 Edit: I want to add that the shape shown in the thumbnail is a simple wireframe-only object, but actual solid-rendered objects are possible to use as bone shapes as well.>

The third method could be to assign the armature's bones to a secondary low-resolution object that is set to only show up in preview, while the final object is hidden in preview and will only show up in render.

If you aren't animating or posing an object:
You could also parent your low-res object to the final resolution object, and set them to show in preview, hide in render and hide in preview, show in render, respectively

Comment: "The third method could be to assign the armature's bones to a secondary low-resolution object that is set to only show up in preview, while the final object is hidden in preview and will only show up in render."
My question basically was how to create this.

Comment: If you know how to model the "true" object and how to assign it to an armature, it shouldn't be too hard to assign the armature to an additional object, i think. Once assigned, open the "Outliner" editor type found in the button with up and down arrows next to an icon, which is to the left side of p much any rectangular Area on Blender's interface. There, locate the objects you want to show/hide in render and make them invisible in the preview area by clicking the eye to the right of their name, and/or make them invisible in the final render by clicking the camera to the right as well.

Comment: Is there also a similar solution for not animated objects (apart from using empties, because they don't work in particle systems)?

Comment: @piegames Displaying low-resolution placeholders for objects that aren't even going to use an armature? Sure, the first subdivision method applies there too, or you could also parent your low-res object to the final resolution object, and set them to show in preview, hide in render and hide in preview, show in render, respectively.

Comment: Even particle systems don't work with children either, you suggested solution is working in all other cases. You could add it into your answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 1):

If they are using subdivided models with the *Subsurf* modifier there are two subdivision levels, one for rendering, and one for OpenGL viewport display.

Many other modifiers also have separate detail levels both for rendering and display purposes, like the *Screw Modifier* or the *Skin Modifier*